# Precise Color Filling with borders in a map

Tags: color, geography, geographics, filling

I would like to have a "SimplifiedArea" borders and color filling for each country exactly following the border line, but I get this rough profile

```
 GeoRegionValuePlot[{GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Spain"], "SimplifiedArea"] -> 11., 
    GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Italy"], "SimplifiedArea"] -> 9,
    GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Austria"], "SimplifiedArea"] -> 5}, 
    ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[#], Red] &), ImageSize -> 1000,
    GeoRange -> {{34, 60}, {-17, 30}}, 
    GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", "Land" -> White, "Ocean" -> None, "Border" -> Lighter@Gray}, GeoProjection -> "Robinson"]
```

[image]

Is there any way to draw the same borders are coloured?
Best

Answer (score 1):

```
PlotStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Thick, Opacity[0.5], Gray}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GeoBackground -> None` and use `"SimplifiedArea"` polygons for all countries:

```
europe = EntityList @ EntityClass["Country", "EuropeExtended"];

assoc1 = Association[GeoVariant[#, "SimplifiedArea"] -> LightGray & /@ europe];

assoc2 = AssociationThread[GeoVariant[Entity["Country", #], "SimplifiedArea"] & /@
     {"Spain", "Italy", "Austria"}, {11, 9, 5}];

assoc = AssociateTo[ assoc1, assoc2];

GeoRegionValuePlot[assoc, 
 ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[#], Red] &), ImageSize -> 1000, 
 GeoRange -> {{34, 60}, {-17, 30}}, 
 GeoBackground -> None, GeoProjection -> "Robinson"]
```

[image]